# Clarification about ring and ideal.

Tags: ring-theory

Just to clarify things:

**1)** Is an ideal also a ring ?

I would say yes since $(I,+)$ is a subgroup and $ab\in I$ for all $a,b\in I$ and $a(b+c)=ab+ac\in I$. The only thing is that $1$ is not necessary in $I$, so it's not necessary a unitaire ring.

**2)** Is a subring an ideal ?

I would say yes by definition.

**3)** Let $A$ a ring. Is $A$ a maximal ideal ? To me it is since it contain all ideal, and thus it's maximal for the inclusion. The problem is that I have a theorem in my course that say $a$ is invertible if and only if $a$ doesn't belong to any maximal ideal... Therefore, I don't understand.

**4)** Let $a\in A$ and $A$ a ring. Is the ideal $(a)$ in fact $aA$ ?

**5)** If yes, is $(a,b)=aAbA=abA$ ?

Thank you for you explanations.

Comment: What is your definition of a ring? (The answer to 1 depends on this; in some textbooks it is in other it isn't.) Also is your ring comutative? This is relevantfor 4.

Comment: No, not every subring is an ideal. Which definition? There is one piece of the definition of ideal which is stronger than the subring definition.

Comment: (3) If we defined "maximal ideal" that way, it would not be a very useful definition.  Read the definition of "maximal ideal" again.

Comment: (5) You, the product of two ideals is not the same as the same.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: What do you mean for (5) ? that $(a,b)\neq aAbB$ ? But is (4) correct ? For (3), if $B$ is a subring of $A$, then $ab\in B$ doesn't necessary hold, right ? So it's not an ideal, but is an ideal a subring ? But I'm not sure if $1\in I$ if $I$ is an ideal, to me, $1$ not necessarily belong to $I$, and it is in $I$ only if $I$ has an invertible element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes, an ideal can also be considered a ring, by the argument you give.
2. No, a subring might not be an ideal, since the definition of a subring $R\subseteq S$ does not require that $aR\in R$ for every $a\in S$.
3. Typically we require maximal ideals to be proper ideals (an ideal $I$ of a ring $R$ is proper if $I\neq R$).
4. $(a)=\{ra|r\in A\}=Aa$. (Note that this is a left ideal...we could similarly define the right ideal.)
5. $(a,b)=\{r_1a+r_2b|r_1,r_2\in A\}\neq abA$.

Comment: Thank you :-)  For 1), do we have $1\in I$ or not necessarily ? For $5$, can we see $(a,b)$ as $aA+bA=(a+b)A$ ?

Comment: @Rick no $1$ is not in $I$ (except $I$ is the full ring). An ideal is a ring if your definition of ring does not impose a  $1$ for a ring.  For 5, yes it is $aA + bA$ but this is not the same as $(a+b)A$. Note that in the former case you can mutliply $a$ and $b$ by different elements.

Comment: @Rick you should also be careful what your definition of $(a)$ is. it could be smalles ideal that contain $a$, in which case you need an extra argument.

Comment: On (4), I would think that $\{ra\mid r\in A\}$ is $Aa$, not $aA$.

Comment: @quid: Thank you. I just have a problem to understand. How can $1a\in I$ if $a\in I$ and $1\notin I$ ? Normally, if $ab\in I$, then $a,b\in I$ no ? And if it's wrong, do we have that $ab\in I$ imply $a\in I$ or $b\in I$ or we don't have necessarily this result ?

Comment: @EricWofsey Thanks, fixed it.

Comment: @Rick That is not true for any ideal except for the one which is the entire ring (viewed as an ideal).

Comment: @Rick It is not at all true that $ab \in I$ implies  both of $a,b$ are in $I$. Note that for $a\in I$ and $b\in A$ you always have $ab\in I$ by the property of ideal. So if this were true you'd have all elements in $I$. For the "or" version, this is precisely the condition for an ideal to be a prme ideal. Thus it is not a property of all ideal, but it is an interesting propety an ideal can have.

Comment: Every thing is clear now. Thanks to all of you :-) @EricWofsey: the notation $(a)$ refer to the ideal of a commutatif ring, I think it doesn't matter $aA$ or $Aa$ since $ar=ra$.

Comment: Does someone has a example of ideal such that $ab\in I$ but neither $a$ nor $b$ in $I$ ? I don't find any.

Comment: Take $A=\mathbb Z$ and $I=6\mathbb Z$. $$3\cdot 2\in I$$ but neither $3$ nor $2$ are in $I$.

Answer (score 0):

More generally, the smallest ideal containing $a$ is given by

$$(a)=\Big{\{}ra+as+na+\sum_{i=1}^{m} r_{i}as_{i} | r,s,r_{i},s_{i} \in A, n\in\mathbb{Z}, m\in\mathbb{N}^*\Big{\}}$$

When the ring has an identity, then

$$(a)=\Big{\{}\sum_{i=1}^{m} r_{i}as_{i} | r,s,r_{i},s_{i} \in A, m\in\mathbb{N}^*\Big{\}}$$

If $a$ is in the center of $A$, then

$$(a)=\{ra+na|r\in A, n \in \mathbb{Z}\}$$

$aA$ and $Aa$ are also ideals of $A$, but they only contain $a$ if the ring has an identity. If the ring has an identity and if $a$ is in the center of $A$, then $(a)=aA=Aa$.